# Merge two datasets that have lists and keep the list after merge using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, merge

I have this two dataframes that I am having a hard time to merge:

```
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [ ["001",  "001"], ["001"], ["007",   "001"]]})
```

OUTPUT:

```
    id
    0   [001, 001]
    1   [001]
    2   [007, 001]
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'id': [ "001", "007"],'name': ['Name01', 'Name02']})
```

OUTPUT:

```
id  name
0   001 Name01
1   007 Name02
```

And I want to arrive is this:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame({'id':  [ ["001",  "001"], ["001"], ["007",   "01"]],
                    'name': [ ['Name01','Name01'], ['Name01'], ['Name02', 'Name01']]})
```

OUTPUT:

```
    id  name
0   [001, 001]  [Name01, Name01]
1   [001]   [Name01]
2   [007, 01]   [Name02, Name01]
```

My problem is that I can merge, but I am not managing to put in the format I want. What I have at the moment is here:

```
pd.DataFrame(df2.merge(df1.explode('id'), on= 'id')).groupby('id').agg(lambda x: x.tolist())
```

OUTPUT:

```
id   name
001 [Name01, Name01, Name01, Name01]
007 [Name02]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mapping` by dictionary created by `df2` in list comprehension, what should be faster like `explode` and aggregate `list`, the best test in real data:

```
d = df2.set_index('id')['name'].to_dict()
df1['name'] = [[d[y] for y in x if y in d] for x in df1['id']]
print (df1)
           id              name
0  [001, 001]  [Name01, Name01]
1       [001]          [Name01]
2  [007, 001]  [Name02, Name01]
```

Comment: I guess this should be faster than using `explode` and `map`, right?

Comment: @ShubhamSharma - I think `merge`/ `map` here is fast, but bottlenck is mainly `.agg(list)` and also is slow `.explode('id')`. So finally not so good performance, in my opinion

Comment: That's what i think hence i deleted the answer, but i will surely test the performance of the both the approaches, BTW good answer.

Answer (score 3):

We can do `explode` + `merge`

```
df1=df1.explode('id').reset_index().merge(df2,how='left').groupby('index').agg(list)
               id              name
index                              
0      [001, 001]  [Name01, Name01]
1           [001]          [Name01]
2      [007, 001]  [Name02, Name01]
```

Or just `map` and assign

```
df1['name']=df1.id.explode().map(df2.set_index('id').name).groupby(level=0).agg(list)
0    [Name01, Name01]
1            [Name01]
2    [Name02, Name01]
Name: id, dtype: object
```